# mypy error: Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched

Tags: python, python-typing

`mypy` gives this error:

`error: Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader`

with this code:

```py
from typing import overload, Literal
from random import randint

@overload
def func() -> dict[str, float]:
    ...
        
@overload    
def func() -> Literal['']: # this is the error line
    ...

def func() -> dict[str, float] | Literal['']:
    x = randint(1, 10) % 2
    if x:
        return ''
    else:
        return {'foo':12.34}
        
print(func())
```

I tried switching the order of the two `@overload` defs, but that didn't help.  I've seen this error message when trying to overload `int` and `float` or `int` and `bool`, which I can understand given the similarities, but I don't understand the problem here.  I also tried `str` instead of `Literal['']` to no avail; similar problems with returning `0` or `False`.  I'm using Python 3.10.4 and mypy 0.960.

I'm returning `''` in the real code to signal an error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation you linked above, `@overload`

> The @overload decorator allows describing functions and methods that support multiple **different combinations of argument types**.

It is useful for showing that a function returns different types depending on the types of its arguments. A classic example is `__getitem__()` which returns a single value if an `int` is passed as an argument, but returns a list if a `slice` object is passed as an argument.

In your code, the overloaded `func()` have the same signature (e.g., no arguments) so `mypy` can't tell which return type it should use. If `mypy` is analyzing this code:

```
x = func()
```

how does it know the correct return type?

Answer (score 1):

```py
def func() -> dict[str, float] | Literal['']:
```

is sufficient. You either return dict or literal depending on `if` inside the function.

Simply remove the code above. `overload` would be helpful if you'd have different inputs types and depending on them different output types, while in this example it doesn't depend on input arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`@overload` is for functions that *accept* different types of arguments (as opposed to returning different types). Since `func()` doesn't take any arguments, you don't need `@overload`:

```py
from typing import overload, Literal
from random import randint

def func() -> dict[str, float] | Literal['']:
    x = randint(1, 10) % 2
    if x:
        return ''
    else:
        return {'foo':12.34}

print(func())
```